# Creating Webmap using QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I am a market analyst working in real estate and would like to create a private webmap for internal use or to send to clients.

What I would like to do is create a web map similar to this one (https://maps.calgary.ca/myCalgaryServices/). This map allows a user to select a point or address, and query all features within a defined radius.

Based on the found criteria within the defined distance, beyond the web interface, one could create a "report" that lists the found features within it. For example, the report would include all Park features found within the distance, and provide how far away they are, or some other information contained within an attribute table.

Is this possible with QGIS, or would I have to branch out to something like Mapbox, ESRI's web maps, or another service?

Comment: See this for a start: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334424/88814

Comment: I think one of your challenges will be the fact that you want to publish it internal AND external. External usage suggests some level of security and web page hosting, so you are looking at a solution beyond just publishing a simple web map.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin called QGIS2Web that you install on QGIS desktop. This plugin allows you to export your styled layers to the Web with base layers such as OpenStreet Map. It generates a Web Map for you. The functionalities may be limited and so is the styling, you may need to do some advancement here and there but it relatively does a good job for nonprogrammers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible with QGIS

No.

QGIS is a desktop GIS package.

You would have to look at an online GIS like ArcGIS online, OpenLayers, MapBox, Leaflet, QGIS server, etc...

Comment: QGIS would be used in the context of managing the data sources and potentially, publishing of web services via plugins. Other capability may need extension of the web mapping solution. So I wouldn't say its a flat out 'no', but rather QGIS needs to be complimented with additional solutions, but can be used as part of the overall solution.